# How to simulate not enough memory in suspended state

Tags: windows-8.1, emulation, tablet, resume, suspend

I want to test suspend/resume functionality of my app. In suspending event I save required data and I want to simulate that my tablet hasn't enough memory and it released my app data while it was in suspended state so that when I resume, it will load saved data in resuming event. In visual studio I use Suspend button from Debug Location panel to suspend the app, but when I resume it I see that all the data, e.g. values that were enetered to textboxes, are still exist. How to force the simulater to release my app data while it's in suspended state?

Comment: Create another app that will use up all the memory after you suspend the app.

Comment: It's not convenient, I think there should be standard feature in visual studio or in emulator that will do that for me. For instance In Windows Phone 7 project properties there was an option to force switching of app to tombstoned state during suspend.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/08/23/new-visual-studio-2012-debugging-features-for-the-windows-8-app-lifecycle-model.aspx